# Postfixadmin can't connect to mysql database

Tags: mysql, postfix

postfixadmin can't connect to mysql database.

Error: Can't connect to database
Please edit the $CONF['database_*'] parameters in config.local.php.

DEBUG INFORMATION:
Connect: Access denied for user 'postfixadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

in config.local.php everything seems to be fine and using

```
mysql -u postfixadmin -p
```

i can easly connect to this database using the same password.

this is my config.local.php

```
$CONF['database_type'] = 'mysqli';
$CONF['database_host'] = 'localhost';
$CONF['database_user'] = 'postfixadmin';
$CONF['database_password'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
$CONF['database_name'] = 'postfixadmin';

$CONF['database_use_ssl'] = false;
$CONF['database_ssl_key'] = NULL;
$CONF['database_ssl_cert'] = NULL;
$CONF['database_ssl_ca'] = NULL;
$CONF['database_ssl_ca_path'] = NULL;
$CONF['database_ssl_cipher'] = NULL;
$CONF['database_prefix'] = '';
```

im using raspban 10 buster on raspberrypi 4B and i installed everything directly under the host

in /var/log/nginx/postfixadmin_error.log i have this

2019/12/29 23:04:05 [error] 12968#12968: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: ERROR: directory /usr/share/postfixadmin/lib/../templates_c doesn't exist or isn't writeable for the webserver" while reading response header from upstream, client: 8.8.8.8, server: mail.example.com, request: "GET /login.php HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "mail.example.com", referrer: "https://mail.example.com/setup.php

i replaced my ip with 8.8.8.8 and my domain name with example.com

i created folder /usr/share/postfixadmin/lib/templates_c

this is permissions
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Jan  2 10:34 templates_c. then i restarted nginx and postfix services, but nothing worked.

in /var/log/mail.err i also get this error

Jan  2 10:38:46 kontakt postfix/proxymap[17706]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf: No such file or directory

i would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: i just changed my password in config.inc.php instead of config.local.php and everything works, but still i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT ... @'%'
```

includes

```
GRANT ... @'8.8.8.8'
```

but *not*

```
GRANT ... @localhost
```

If you need both socket (localhost) and TCP/IP access, you must provide two `GRANTs`.

Answer (score 0):

In this command `mysql -u postfixadmin -p` you have a blank password, but in your config file, you have `$CONF['database_password'] = 'XXXXXXXX';`. Try to remove XXXXX with just `$CONF['database_password'] = '';`

Comment: man. when i type mysql -u postfixadmin -p mysql is asking me for password. I just replaced my password with XXXXXX in this file.

Comment: ok, I understand well. Do you have more logs from postfixadmin ?

Comment: where should i search for postfixadmin logs?

Comment: How did you install it ? with docker or directly on the host ? are you using linux ou ubuntu ? normally you installed under /var/something. Logs are inside...You can check your httpd logs in /var/logs/

Comment: i edited my post